# Suggestions for incorporating wireless capability to a simple sensor based project

Tags: stm32, embedded, wireless

So I have a simple application that involves reading the input over terminal via UART, and then responding accordingly, be it toggling an LED or outputting a sensor reading over I2C.  As a step up, I have been thinking about incorporating some wireless capability so the data could be sent/read over the air i.e WiFi or Bluetooth.

I personally think for this simple application, Bluetooth would be more than enough considering even the max standard the baud rate (0.256Mbps) is lesser than what bit rate you could achieve with Bluetooth (~2Mbps) but from a learning standpoint, what would be the suggested approach?

A simple use case that I thought of with BLE was to connect to a mobile app, and send/receive data over the air and UART from the module to the MCU.

For WiFi, I haven't done much research but I'd have to set up a local server first, connect the module to wifi internet, set up get/post requests and some backend processing I guess.

I have an STM32F4 MCU.

Comment: This question is a bit broad and opinion-ish for this site.  You're right that BLE is in theory a simpler fit, but implementation details can get complex.  In either case you probably want a suitable chip the needed native interface, like a nRF51822/52832/52840 or an ESP8266/ESP32 rather than your STM32.  In theory you can do a split system with a host processor and a radio one, but that also adds complexity if there's not a whole lot that needs to go on beside the communication.  You may just want to get some evaluation modules and experiment before making a decision, they're both cheap.

Comment: how different is `nRF51822` from say a cheaper module HC06? and it also contains the MCU like ESP8266 hence no need of STM32? Ideally i'd want to use peripheral drivers that I wrote for I2C/UART, and would want to stick to STM32.

Comment: If this is a one-off or very low-volume project, I highly recommend just connecting to the UART of a Raspberry Pi. Then the whole world of off-the-shelf Linux networking & web tools is open to you, plus you can SSH in to the Pi to quickly develop. IMO the only reason not to would be if you're really space/power-constrained.

Comment: _" As a step up, I have been thinking about incorporating some wireless capability so the data could be sent/read over the air i.e WiFi or Bluetooth."_ - Why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott do you have any suggestion for enhancing the existing project? This is solely for learning/employment purposes

Comment: For 'learning/employment' I suggest trying every option you can (even those you may not think are the best). That way you get more experience and learn more.

Comment: @BruceAbbott but there has to be a reason to use a specific HW over the other

Answer (score 1):

For choosing any wireless medium for a project, you should consider it's long term effect. Certain parameters to be considered are-

1. Power Consumption
2. Range
3. Susceptance to noise or interference due to nearby modules already present
4. Ease of upgrade for future purposes.
5. Cost( best use of already available modules)
   If the modules are mobile or battery-powered, You should consider power consumption. Bluetooth BLE can be a good choice to be considered.
   For range, if the modules are very close within meters, a simple module of RF433MHz will work fine. For long-range LoRa or Zigbee can be considered.
   If you have already installed some wireless modules nearby using the same frequency may cause interference. This is also applicable for many Bluetooth modules. Generic wireless modules like nRF24 or similar RF modules can have channels overcome this. On the other hand, Wifi uses frequency hopping so it easily manages through many devices.

Which kind of technology you should use depends on the particular use case, and what you want to do with the data after receiving it. You can receive the data on your mobile phone or any microcontroller.
I would suggest using a Wifi module for connecting to your home router or LAN. Then you can access the data across all your devices using its local IP address. This architecture uses your already available modules and has upgrade options. You can also easily use multiple nodes in this manner for data transmission.

Although it depends on your use case and your solution may vary greatly.

Comment: I don't need long-distance for it. Some of the BLE modules I have looked at (i.e nRF51822) is a full-blown MCU with some peripherals already in it. I want to use my existing STM32 board and probably interface a module with it. 
In terms of implementation, is rf433Mhz relatively easier? have only seen an arduino code

Comment: rf433Mhz are very commonly available in the market and are very easy to use. Using rf433Mhz, security can be an issue. 43MhzRf uses Amplitude Shift Key(ASK) technique, you need to search for ASK library for STM32, or you can write your own also.